# Moving items between lists destroys Infopath form

Tags: 2010, infopath, list-form

Situation (SP 2010, InfoPath Designer 2010):

- ListBlue has a form customized with InfoPath, distinct blue background
- create a template from ListBlue
- create new ListRed from that template
- add more columns to ListRed, customize with InfoPath to include new columns and some more rules in the form, change background to red
- add some items to ListRed, add some items to ListBlue
- both lists now have distinct IP forms and a few list items
- use Site Settings > Content and Structure to move some list items from the original ListBlue to the new ListRed

**Issue:** ListRed now has reverted back to the original ListBlue form and all the customizations done to the ListRed form have disappeared. ALL ListRed items now open with the ListBlue form, even the ones that were created with the ListRed form.
When the ListRed form is opened in InfoPath, the field list shows only the original ListBlue fields and the Update Fields dialog appears ("One or more fields in the SharePoint list have changed. Do you want InfoPath to update the set of available fields? ...").

In SharePoint designer, the template.xsn for ListRed has the same (old) time stamp as the ListBlue template.xsn, so clearly the xsn has been overwritten.

That just happened to me and I can reproduce the scenario.

Questions:

- How can this be explained? How can a list item cause an override of the list form xsn file?
- How can this be reversed? Restore from backup, obviously, but any other way?

Ideas welcome.

Comment: Well after the anniversary of the initial question I came across this. If this is still an issue for you, the following MS article might be helpful: [Move a published form template to a new SharePoint library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Move-a-published-form-template-to-a-new-SharePoint-library-2a2aac61-3180-40fc-b306-61e8d7829bf8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1). It's not exactly the same, but might suit for you.

Comment: @moe Nice try, but that does not apply. My issue is with a SharePoint **List** whose form is customised with InfoPath, not with an InfoPath form that is published to a forms library.

Comment: By the way: restore from backup only restored the list definition and list items. The InfoPath form was not restored and I had to build the whole thing back from scratch. That cost me a weekend that I could have spent with my family.

Comment: Right, took me a couple of reads to understand the issue correctly. The issues with a foreign language, let's blame it once again :). Your very first question is barely answerable, unless we have an InfoPath's/SharePoint's principal architect over here. I doubt you want to trouble yourself with this issue nowadays, but would be interesting to see the version details of the list and how they reflect the change. Additionally, what ULS shows.

Comment: @moe Water down the drain. I have learned the hard way and I feel this is a bug. I will not EVER try to do this again.

Comment: I'm quite confident of that too, as the behavior is such an unusual (, and after lately facing a few other, totally unrelated bugs). Additionally, the troubleshooting through trial and error is far from ideal, so why bother.